# Terminology: "left homotopical"?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, terminology

I first asked this on StackExchange, but no dice; so apologies in advance if this question really belongs there.

Suppose a functor $F \colon \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ between two model categories (i) sends cofibrant objects to cofibrant objects and (ii) sends weak equivalences between cofibrant objects to weak equivalences (between cofibrant objects).

Is there a standard name for this kind of functor? It's not necessarily left Quillen, so calling it "left homotopical" seems reasonable, but I wasn't able to find a reference in the literature. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the terminology of [Dwyer, Hirschhorn, Kan, and Smith] this would be a left deformable functor, but that is a weaker condition.

Comment: There is not any standard terminology for that. Since this property means that the total left derived functor exists as right Kan extension (and is constructed in the usual way using cofibrant objects), this could be called "left derivable" But "left homotopical" looks too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Zhen Lin and Denis-Charles Cisinski for their comments, as well as "jgon" who commented on the Stack Exchange post. It seems there is no standard terminology for such a functor.

There is, however, a related notion. A functor that preserves weak equivalences between cofibrant objects is said to be *left deformable* in the language of either DHKS "Homotopy Limit Functors on Model Categories and Homotopical Categories" or Blumberg-Riehl "Homotopical resolutions associated to deformable adjunction's." A left deformable functor, however, need not send cofibrant objects to cofibrant objects.